# Apache "undefined" file requested

Tags: javascript, apache, embedded-browser

I am having an interesting error with Apache (I think Apache is the issue). I noticed many of my JavaScript files were not being served. When I went and looked at my Apache logs, I saw a whole slew of:

.... [error] File not found: /webroot/site/undefined .....

I have a strange feeling the issues are related. I am requesting the correct script src paths for sure.

Any reason why the heck "undefined" would be requested?

Additional info: PHP script, clients are embedded IE8 applications.

Comment: This is pretty certainly an error in your Javascript. Look out for any places where JS requests a file named `"webroot/site"+some_variable` - the `some_variable` part is `undefined` for some reason

Comment: Can you call the file directly in the web browser? Is the part after `/webroot/site/` contained in a javascript variable or some other kind of object?

Answer (score 0):

If you really do call the correct script URIs (“script src paths” as you say) the problem can only lie in your apache configuration.

Check your rewrite rules etc.

You may also want to check your access log, whether strange/wrong paths/URLs were called.